# JQuery Selector for multiple elements of one ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DOM structure similar to this:

```
<div id="ans1">
    <input id="in1" />
    <input id="in2" />
</div>
<div id="ans2">
    <input id="in1" />
    <input id="in2" />
</div>
```

How can I select some of the descendants of an ancestor?

Something like:

```
$("#ans1 #in1, #ans1 #in2")
```

Comment: Ids should be unique. You need to update your DOM

Comment: Which elements do you want to select?

Comment: @stevenw00, Inputs inside the `ans1`.

Comment: @Nikhil, why? This DOM Model is almost unavoidable for me.

Comment: `$("#ans1 input")` will do just that. Select all inputs inside `#ans1`

Comment: @techfoobar, I want to select certain elements based on their `id`, not just all of the inputs.

Comment: And ids really have to be unique. You can use classes to identify elements serving a similar purpose.

Comment: in1 and in2 - these 2 ids associated with 2 elements each. Which is not appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the children function

```
$("#ans1").children("#in1, #in2")
```

You should use unique ids thought the DOM, use classes to specify elements that are the same in nature.

change your children to have same class of in1

```
$("#ans1 > .in1")
```

Will select all direct descendants of ans1 with class of in1.

Comment: Although @sumon's answer has more votes, but this post answers my question directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace your 'id's with classes (since ids should be unique), then,

```
<div id="ans1">
    <input class="in1" />
    <input class="in2" />
</div>
<div id="ans2">
    <input class="in1" />
    <input class="in2" />
</div>
```

Then, to select all the descendants of id=ans1 having class="in1", you go like,

```
$('#ans1 .in1')
```

This will return an array of all the .in1 class elements inside id=ans1 element