# Replacing a class on multiple pages with Optimizely

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, optimizely

I'm trying to set up an A/B test using Optimizely to change the color of the add to cart button on all product pages on the site.

Here's the current code on the site

```
<input id="id-for-test" class="add_to_cart_list" value="Add to Cart" name="Add to Cart" type="button"
                                                    onclick='sendToDataLayer("Category Lower", "Add to cart");return cat_add_one_to_cart( "<?= $p["id"] ?>", "<?= $param_sku ?>", "<?= $output_price ?>", "<?= $path ?>", "<?= $can_buy_limit ?>" ,"<?=$this_page_type?>")'/>
```

I'm adding this in the Optimizely code editor and it's not working

```
$('#id-for-test').removeClass('add_to_cart_list').addClass('color-test');
```

Comment: It works on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j61m26u4/)

Comment: You're right, it does work. But it doesn't work when I put it in Optimizely.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Does it find `$('#id-for-test')`? Do you run the code when the document is ready?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, but I don't have a solution. It's applying the color to the first item in all the categories. But it's not replacing the subsequent ones. I edited the fiddle so you can see the issue.

Comment: If it works for the first but not the rest, sounds like it's because your above code will only target the element with the id ```id-for-test```. To target multiple elements you could use a shared class, for example. See these resources [here](https://help.optimizely.com/Build_Experiments/The_Code_Editor_and_Variation_Code#Changing_multiple.2C_similar_elements_at_once) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355393/jquery-selector-for-multiple-elements-of-one-ancestor). This works in jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4zba0064/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each cart `input` element a common class such as `cart-class`:

```
<input id="id-for-test" class="cart-class add_to_cart_list" value="Add to Cart" name="Add to Cart" type="button"
    onclick='sendToDataLayer("Category Lower", "Add to cart");return cat_add_one_to_cart( "<?= $p["id"] ?>", "<?= $param_sku ?>", "<?= $output_price ?>", "<?= $path ?>", "<?= $can_buy_limit ?>" ,"<?=$this_page_type?>")'/>
```

Then query based on class instead of ID:

```
$('.cart-class').removeClass('add_to_cart_list').addClass('color-test');
```

IDs are supposed to be unique, so the query just stops looking after it finds it's first instance. Use a class so it applies the change to all instances.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works. Can't believe I missed that about id vs. class.

Comment: @Amanda No problem! If you found this answer correct, you should mark it as so

Comment: Looks like the comment i suggested on your original question worked then ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$('input.add_to_cart_list').removeClass('add_to_cart_list').addClass('color-test');
```